# How can i save a raw text on a website to be same for all users that visit it?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I am trying to make a Key system that generates a random code every 24 hours to use it on a c# form but when i generate a number then i refresh it regenerates i want it to save so it can be same for all users accessing my site!

```
<head>
<script>  
setInterval(function(){  
    document.body.innerHTML = "";
    document.write(Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000000000)+1)); 
 }, 20000);
</script>     
</head>
</html>
```

So any idea on how to do that?

Comment: generate on, or send it to the server, save it on the server, send it to people loading the page.

Comment: Your easiest bet would probably be to generate it server-side and store it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to understand some concepts here.
Every time a user goes to a webpage, the page HTML, JavaScript and CSS is downloaded and parsed by the users browser.
This means that each user has their own version of the webpage.

If you want to show every user the same, they'd need the same source of truth, which is your server. So you could do something like

```
window.onload = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(<API>);
    const truth = await reponse.json();
    document.body.innerHTML = truth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Joe! I think that what you are trying to do is not possible to be calculated from JavaScript on the browser, the case being that if you want your key to be shared among your clients, it has to be generated from your server and be served to your clients (your client has no way of knowing what other clients key is if there is no common point of checking (Server)). You need to make an API GET method in your server for your clients to check the current key.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is caching.  You mentioned C#, so I'm adding that tag to this question, as what you are describing would happen on the server, using a server side technology such as ASP.NET.  Caching is a complex topic, but to start with [MSDN page regarding caching in .NET apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/caching-in-net-framework-applications), and specifically [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.8).  The default settings will cause cache entries to expire after 24hrs, and you can provide an event handler that is triggered when a cache entry expires.  Using this, you can provide a function that will generate a store a new, unique key every time the prior day's key expires.

Now, to provide that key to the client there are a myriad of approaches, and which one to apply would be context specific.  For example consider whether you are returning this with the initial response, or if you are returning this as the result of a subsequent AJAX request.